# Log likelihhood of a new sequence based on a trasition probability in Markov chain

Tags: python, r, markov-chains

Suppose I have a transition matrix like this:

```
   A     B     C
A 0.2   0.3   0.5

B 0.8   0.1   0.1

C 0.3   0.3   0.4
```

I can get the log likelihood of this by the following formula:

```
$L_{mc}=\sum_{i=1}^M\sum_{j=1}^M.N_{ij}.ln(T_{ij})$
```

If I have a new sequence like `A, A, B, A, C, C, A`, How can I calculate the log-likelihood of the new sequence based on the above transition probability?

Comment: What have you tried so far? Take a look on [How to ask a good question in Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and [How to create a minimal, complete, and verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: Basically, I am looking for the appropriate way to solve this rather than coding. But I am struggling with it.

Comment: In this case, it is more appropriate to place your question at [Cross Validated](https://stats.stackexchange.com/), where people will be able to discuss the proper approach. Here, in Stack Overflow, we are focused in programming questions & answers.

Comment: I am also thinking so. Thank you for your suggestion